# Unity and Admob Integration

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob, ads

I have added the admob Package to my project but when i try to build the apk file this error shows up:

[image]

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/PC-Boulot/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\PROGRAM FILES\UNITY\EDITOR\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Error:Invalid command dx
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 64
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

Answer (score 0):

What Unity version are you using ? this used to happen due to a Unity bug which has been resolved since then.

Try to migrate your project to Unity 2017.1 to see if that helps.